# html code in javascript not getting the id to open to another window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a html inside a javascript. My problem is I cant call the id in my html code. Can someone help me with this?

My code:

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
  // customer notification
  notifications.initMenu({
    projects: '#projects1'
  });

  $.getJSON('/Customer/ForCustomerNotif' + '?userId=' + userId, function (savedCusNotif) {
    $.each(savedCusNotif, function () {
      var ID = this["ID"];
      var workerId = this["WorkerID"];
      var Name = this["Name"];
      var DateApplied = this["DateCreated"];
      var Position = this["Position"];
      var Read = this["IsRead"];
      var WorkerID = this["WorkerID"];
      var ClientCusId = this["Client_CustomerID"];
      var positionId = this["PositionID"];
      var options = (Read == true) ? {
        id: ID,
        unread: 'unread',
        category: "projects",
        message: '<b>' + Name + '</b>' + '<br/>' + " is applied in the  " + '<b>' + Position + '</b>' + " " + "position" + " on " + '<br/>' + DateApplied + "." 
      } : {
        id: ID,
        read: 'read',
        category: "projects",
        message: '<b>' + Name + '</b>' + '<br/>' + " is applied in the  " + '<b>' + Position + '</b>' + " " + "position" + " on " + '<br/>' + DateApplied + "."
        //im calling this link for redirection in another window.
        +'<a href="" id="redirect"  class="redirect">View </a>'
      };
      notifications.createNotification(options);
      // I tried to call the id but doesn't work.

      $("#redirect").click(function() {
        alert("get link");
        var redirect = $(this).attr('href', '/Customer/ViewAppliedWorkersProfile?workerId=' + WorkerID + '&positionId=' + positionId + '&positionIds=' + positionId);
        window.open(redirect, 'width=900,height=800,left=190,top=100,screenX=190,screenY=100,resizable=no,resizable=0,resizable=false,scrollbars=yes');    
      }); 
    });
  });  
</script>
```

I'm using ttwnotificationmenu.js from www.codebasehero.com.
So my problem is getting the id in the html code hope someone will help me with this.

Comment: how did you try to call id ?find HTML elements in the DOM? where you want to call ?did you try document.getElementById("idofelement"); ???

Comment: yes ive tried that but did not work. :(

Comment: it shows what ? did console shows any error messages ?

Comment: include html codes inside js like document.getElementById('divid').innerHTML = "html code here"; then try to call

Comment: yes when im using document.getelementbyid () it shows "TypeError: cannot read property 'click' of null"

Comment: okay..ill try that one.

Comment: ok try and let me know if any error comes

Comment: have a question , did you try to get one windows html element's id  in another window ?

Comment: not yet sir. what im trying to do is.. after you click the html link that will open the new window.

Comment: sir, im getting error in innerHTML. try to  put it in a function to call a onclick event in html. Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: i tried to use document.getElementsbyClassName()..it has no error but not went to my alert.

Comment: Please Don't call me sir. In stack overflow everyone are friends.

Comment: where is your div ? are you trying to innerhtml to a div ??check whether your div is placed below your script , if it is like that then place the div before the script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70117/discussion-between-arunprasanth-kv-and-vincent-gumera).